# Aqueduct ORM missing FROM clause

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I have an Aqueduct project using the ORM, with data objects like so:

Relationships:

1. User has many Things (Many to one)
2. A Thing has one Thinglet (of one kind, one to one)
3. A Thing has one Thinglet (of another kind, one to one)

```
class _User {
  String userId;

  ...
  ManagedSet<Thing> thingRef;
}

class _Thing {
  @Relate(#thingRef)
  User user;

  @Relate(#oneKindRef)
  Thinglet oneKind;

  @Relate(#anotherKindRef)
  Thinglet anotherKind;
}

class _Thinglet {
  ...

  ManagedSet<Thing> oneKindRef;
  ManagedSet<Thing> anotherKindRef;
}
```

Now, I want to update the `Thing` for a `User`, so I do this:

```
Thing myThing = ...;
final query = Query<Thing>(context)
  ..where((thing) => thing.user.userId).equalTo(someUserId)
  ..values = myThing;

final result = await query.updateOne();
```

This throws a SQL error saying `missing FROM-clause entry for table "t1"`

What exactly am I missing here? I know the model is fine because `insert`s and `fetch`s are working fine, and the data in the database looks fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your ‘where’ is missing an expression, eg ‘equalTo’:

```
  ..where((thing) => thing.user.userId).equalTo(1)
```

Comment: My bad, I actually do have it, missed it while writing the question. Updated.

Comment: Ok I see now. Is `userId` the primary key of `User`? If not, this query won't work because you can't (currently) filter on the columns on another table using `where` this way.

Comment: No, it is not. userId is a string public id (I don't want to use row ids as public id), and I can't set a string as primary key, if I'm not wrong. I guess I can first fetch the user by userId then query here with the row I'd, but that will take two queries. Any way I can do it in one query?

Comment: Ok, I have implemented it with two queries. Could you update your answer with your above comment (about query not working if `userId` is not the primary key) so I can accept that as the answer?